# Java ws Jboss 7 soap header

Tags: java, xml, soap, jboss

I need to read a SOAP header.
Below is the xml being sent:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://services.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://tech.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:header id="ref1">
        <session_id>63949bc1878725afd28cc8283ec3252a</session_id>
        <ip_address>127.0.0.1</ip_address>
        <user_agent>Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0</user_agent>
        <last_activity>1362395880</last_activity>
        <user_data></user_data>
        <username>serge</username>
        <logged_in>true</logged_in>
    </ns2:header>
    <ns2:header href="#ref1"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getInvo>
        <id>1</id>
    </ns1:getInvo>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I need to read the inside the ns2:header that contains session_id etc...

Comment: Also read about [SOAPHeader](http://www.j2ee.me/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPHeader.html) API

Comment: Do you know what is the type of the context object? Is it javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext? Did the accepted answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read using below code

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage=  context.getMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
```

We can directly apply parsing on soapheader like following

```
NodeList nodes =soapHeader.getElementsByTagName("param");
```

Comment: What is the type of the context object? Is it `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext`?